# What does the last digit mean in a Piper Arrow model number?

Tags: piper-pa-28

The Piper Arrow's model is PA-28R-201. At first, I thought that 201 means horsepower but the Arrow's HP is 200 so I figured that's not the case. What does it stand for?

Answer (score 1):

The number notes the model

PA-28R-180 180bhp Cherokee Arrow with the ‘Hershey Bar’ wing.

PA-28R-200 200bhp Arrow II with the lengthened fuselage.

PA-28R-201 200bhp Arrow III with the tapered wing.

PA-28RT-201 200bhp Arrow IV with the tapered wing and T tail.

PA-28RT-201T Turbocharged Arrow IV.

The Arrow III was introduced in 1977 with the tapered wing and larger stabilator.  This improved low speed handling characteristics and increased the total fuel capacity from 50 to 77 gallons.

Comment: The 200 was the tapered wing and the stretch.  201 is just the GW change.

Comment: Not according to the type certificate.  Those were features of the Arrow III, not the II. (http://www.airweb.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/a44b41c7e7d7d7458625753c004f4a2d/%24FILE/2A13.pdf)

Comment: Ok I was going by Wikipedia, and I forgot my normal golden rule to NEVER TRUST FREAKIN' WIKIPEDIA!!! lol

Comment: I think the list is incomplete as there are some 200 HP Piper Arrow I models. Only the very first ones were 180 HP but they switched to 200 HP before the Arrow II. This small detail would make impossible to distinguish from Arrow I (200) and II as both would be PA-28R-200